How compile into APK from GitHub repo?
i am new in this,I want to build this source into APK from this GitHub repository:
https://github.com/seleuco/MAME4droid-2024
How can I do it in windows?what are the steps? I installed Android studio and build to apk is greyed,when i click Run nothing happens
Thanks by read.
I expected compile it into apk to run in Android.
